# How to use download attribute of HTML5 in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Is there any way to use **download** attrribute in thymeleaf as i am unable to download files via html5. I tried to download the files from backend and it works fine but unable to do so through frontend. Any suggestions will be helpful...

```
  <td th:switch="${xraydata.xrayResult}">
       <span th:case="2"><a  href="" th:href="@{/download/csv}">Abnormal but eligible for sputum</a></span>
       <span th:case="1"><a th:href="${path}" target="_blank" th:attr="download">Normal</a></span>
       <span th:case="3"><a  th:href="@{/download/csv}" download>Abnormal but uneligible for sputum</a></span>
  </td>
```

I tried the code in backend for the **th:case="3"** as:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/download/csv",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void downloadFile(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("the participants id is");
    String FILE_PATH="C:/java/020.dcm";
    final String APPLICATION_PDF = "020/dcm";
    File file = getFile(FILE_PATH);
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    response.setContentType(APPLICATION_PDF);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + 
    file.getName());
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
    FileCopyUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());

}
```

Comment: I would avoid setting random headers - especially content length.

Comment: I think Its not about thymeleaf, something is wrong with your controller, as Boris said, remove those headers and call response.flushBuffer(); in the end to see what happens.

Comment: thanks for your concerns but the real problem i am facing here is about download attribute of html5 which cant be used in thymeleaf. Please provide any suggestion regarding how to use download attribute in thymeleaf.

Comment: What is the error?  I'm guessing you just have to make the links look like this: `<a th:href="@{/download/csv}" download="download">Abnormal but uneligible for sputum</a>` but it's hard to tell w/o seeing the stack trace.